# Propel Combining IN and LIKE Query

Tags: php, sql, propel

i have this code to select all records with the date in $date_to_search_string
which is just a variable with comma delimited strings.

client wants to add time on the date which now my query should look like
IN('03/1/2014%','03/2/2014%',etc..)
how can i achieve this kind of query with propel?(newbie propel user).

i can always do something like this though:

```
  WHERE initial_interview_date LIKE '03/1/2014%' OR
        initial_final_date LIKE '03/12014%' OR 
        initial_interview_date LIKE '03/2/2014%' OR
        initial_final_date LIKE '03/2/2014%' OR 
  etc..
```

but that might be a little overkill to do the thing that i want to do,
maybe there's other way around this thing.

**Code:**

```
    $date_to_search_string = implode(",",$date_to_search);

    /* $date_to_search_string:
      string ''03/1/2014','03/2/2014','03/3/2014','03/4/2014','03/5/2014'...
    ***/

    $events = ApplicantDetailsQuery::create()
        ->where("initial_interview_date IN (".$date_to_search_string.") OR final_interview_date IN (".$date_to_search_string.")")
        ->find();

    $events_ii = array();
    $events_fi = array();

    foreach($events as $event) {
        $events_ii[$event->getInitialInterviewDate()][] = $event;
        $events_fi[$event->getFinalInterviewDate()][] = $event;
    }
```

Comment: I don't like how you are proposing to `LIKE` on the dates as strings. Are the date columns dates or strings? Can't you just convert the `initial_interview_date` and `final_interview_date` to dates where they are used in the comparison?

Comment: the clients adds date using datetimepicker and the record is saved as string, i think you're proposing that i convert it to timestamp/date and save it?

Comment: Yes, if you have a string in the database with a date (now date + time) in it, convert the column to a date in the WHERE clause. That will drop off the time, so the IN part will work the same as it used to.

Comment: oh well i just changed the column type to datetime and adjusted my php code and just as you said its working now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SQL DATE command and keep the code the same.

For example:

```
WHERE DATE(initial_interview_date) IN ('03/1/2014', '03/2/2014') OR
    DATE(initial_final_date) IN ('03/1/2014', '03/2/2014')  OR
```

And in Propel:

```
$events = ApplicantDetailsQuery::create()
    ->where("DATE(initial_interview_date) IN ?", $arrayOfDates)
    ->orwhere("DATE(final_interview_date) IN ?", $arrayOfDates)
    ->find();
```